# How can I share/sync bookmarks/favorites between multiple Google Chrome/apps users?

Tags: google-chrome, sync, bookmarks

I pretty much think everything is in the title. I'd like to know if I can easily share and sync my bookmarks/favorites with another Chrome user?

I don't want to be sending emails with "Hey! Here's a link, what do you think about that?" any more. And then forget about the link, and also forget to store it on both sides. I don't want to use a Google Doc to do save those links (but maybe this is the only solution for the moment?).

Answer (score 1):

You have the option of making your bookmarks public or private on [Delicious](https://delicious.com/). So to follow each individual in a group, you can all be in the same Network. Alternatively, you can create a public List on Twitter with members of your group to follow group tweets and bookmarks or use Facebook or Google+ similarly. Of course, while these are good options for sharing, they can't help with sync'ing.